# Hopw to store File.text() value outside of the promise

Tags: javascript, input, promise, filereader

I want to parse the contents of a JSON file and store them in an object property `data.current`, outside of the promise used to read the file:

### HTML

```
<form name="data">
    <label>
        <span>Load Data</span>
        <input type="file" accept="application/json">
    </label>
</form>
```

### JavaScript

```
const data = {
    input: document.forms["data"].querySelector("input"),
    current: {}
}

data.input.addEventListener("change", function(event) {
    if(Object.entries(data.current).length == 0) {
        event.target.files[0].text()
            .then((content) => {
                data.current = JSON.parse(content);
                console.log(data.current)
            });
    console.log(data.current)
    }
});
```

### Outputs

Line 11: `Object { property1: [...], property2: [...], property3: [...] }`

Line 13: `Object { }`

### Expected Outputs

Line 11: `Object { property1: [...], property2: [...], property3: [...] }`

Line 13: `Object { property1: [...], property2: [...], property3: [...] }`

The first `console.log(data.current)` shows a parsed JSON Object, the second one an empty Object. How can I get the parsed JSON outside of the promise?